# Java Robot MousePress() not working on Windows Task Manager

Tags: java, windows, awtrobot, taskmanager, mousepress

**Problem:**

Java Robot's MousePress() works fine 99% of the time, but it does not work on the Task Manager of Windows 8.1 or 10 (I have not tested 7 or lower).

As a matter of fact, when the Task Manager window is selected, even MouseMove() will fail.

**To replicate:**

1. Use the code below, run it once to see that the code works.
2. Open Task Manager (CTRL+Shift+Escape), run the code, then quickly
   select the Task Manager window. The code will finish executing, but the mouse position will not change.

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class RobotMousePressTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Started. Waiting for sleep to finish.");
        Robot r = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        r.mouseMove(4, 4);
        r.mousePress(MouseEvent.getMaskForButton(MouseEvent.BUTTON1));
        System.out.println("Click!");
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone know if there is a way to make it work anyway?
2. Is there an alternative library I can use for MousePress() and MouseMove()?
3. Will I be forced to use native code (JNI) in order to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more digging and testing I found that it has to do with Windows' Administrator user. Any application that does not have Administrator privileges cannot interact with applications that do have Administrator privileges. If I run the application as Administrator, the code does execute correctly, even with Task Manager selected.

So far I have found no other way for this to work.